# Listview displays twice all rows

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have problem with **listview**. I have my main activity called `SecondActivity.java` where I have only **buttons** like for example *kierunkiButton*. After click on this button new activity is created, `KierunkiActivity.java` as you can see below:

```
 kierunkiButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setClass(SecondActivity.this, KierunkiActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);

                            }
       });
```

The new activity, `KierunkiActivity` is a ListActivity as you can see below:

```
public class KierunkiActivity extends ListActivity {

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteData;
    static String kier;
    static ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista_activity2);
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        openAndQueryDatabase();
        displayResultList();
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        //Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Object selectedItem = l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        kier = selectedItem.toString();

        if (position == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(KierunkiActivity.this, MatematykaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(KierunkiActivity.this, MatematykaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
        try {
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
            sqliteData = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor c = sqliteData.rawQuery(
                    "select Kierunek from Kierunki order by _id", null);
            System.out.println("------cursor: " + c.getCount());

            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String kier = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Kierunek"));
                        results.add(kier);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }

            System.out.println("---------" + results.size() + "--------------");
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Could not create or Open the database");
        }

    }

    private void displayResultList() {

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }
```

My problem is that to the listview (in my `KierunkiActivity`) rows are added each time I click *kierunkibutton*.

---

What I mean: First time I click *kierunkibutton* I have 2 rows(correct). When I go back to previous activity and again click *kierunkibutton* I have these old 2 rows AND 2 rows additional (of course the same). And after third time I have six and go on and on. 
I think that I should check if this listview is populated each time after click *kierunkibutton* or remove all rows from this listview. But i don't how to do this.

[image]

**Do you have any idea how to do this?**
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to clear your arraylist before you again tap on this.

Comment: hey please post full code of your KierunkiActivity so we can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `new ArrayList<String>();` from top of code and place it in `openAndQueryDatabase` method.

```
private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
   results = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Comment: have u got something for my issue

Comment: @PoojaDubey, i will say don't.. due to work load, i can not focus on your issue dear..if you have time to wait, i will help but i am in very much tight schedule.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to refresh your ArrayList every time when you click the button. Else it gets loaded with the new items with the existing items.

```
results.clear();
if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String kier = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Kierunek"));
                    results.add(kier);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
```

Just add the clear() statement before you load data to list.

or instantiate you list inside your openAndQueryDatabase() method like this,

```
private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
    results = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Try this, I hope this helps you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The datasource for your adapter is the variable 'results' which you have defined as static:

```
static ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Remove the static keyword and your problem will go away. Static variables persist for the lifetime of your application. So when you leave the activity and the instance is destroyed, the static variables remain. When you come back to the activity and it is created again, the static variables are as they were before and you are adding to what you had previously. Remove the static keyword and the variable will be re-created each time you create the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CursorLoader` and `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` to manage your data cursors (like results from database).

This way you will not hang main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have a member variable, results, which gets appended to each time you call openAndQueryDatabase. This means you are adding to an existing list of items each time and therefore you will get duplicates.

It may be better to have openAndQueryDatabase return the collection of results and then you can pass it into displayResultList.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers!

What I did was as @Chintan Rathod said:

```
private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
   results = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

and everything works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should accept answer my friend instead of posting the same here.. You can accept by just ticking "true" just below particular answer. :)

Comment: This is what I did @Chintan. One "tick" is from me :)